# How to make sure Electrum connects to my private Electrs server and to no other server?

Tags: electrum

I want to connect my Electrum wallet app to my private Electrs server in my local LAN which is also reachable via onion. I want to just use this one server, no other server. My `~/.electrum/config` is

```
{
    "alias": "",
    "auto_connect": false,
    "blockchain_preferred_block": {
        "hash": "000000000019d6689c085ae165831e934ff763ae46a2a6c172b3f1b60a8ce26f",
        "height": 0
    },
    "check_updates": true,
    "config_version": 3,
    "gui_last_wallet": "/Users/$USER/.electrum/wallets/default_wallet",
    "is_maximized": false,
    "oneserver": false,
    "proxy": "socks5:127.0.0.1:9050::",
    "recently_open": [
        "/Users/$USER/.electrum/wallets/default_wallet"
    ],
    "rpcpassword": "",
    "rpcuser": "",
    "server": "something.onion:50002:s",
    "show_channels_tab": true
}
```

This seems to work fine in the sense that I am connected. But I have a lot of nodes in my list under the "Network" settings in Electrum. And this is because the `oneserver` property is set to `false`. If I try to set it to `true` in the config manually, Electrum starts and works fine but the config file is reverted to its old state with `false` in it.

How can I make sure this works?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this happened several times. But in the end the config worked with `true` and now my nodes show only one connection and this is the private server.